# How to retrieve dynamically loaded checkbox values from database?

Tags: c#, windows

I have loaded few checkboxes dynamically on the form based on the database values.
Now when Iam trying to retrieve them back from database and display, controls are displaying but values are not binded.

Below is the code I have used:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is CheckBox)
    {
        CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
        if (cb.Name != "checkBox1")
        {
            foreach (string strName in arrayList)
            {
                if (cb.Name == strName)
                {
                    cb.Checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have stored the checkbox values in the `arraylist`.
`if (cb.Name == strName)` is executing properly but `cb.Checked=true` is not assigned to checkbox.
Can any one help how to bind the value?

Comment: That code should work just fine. Are you sure that the `cb.Name == strName` is true in any case?

Comment: Yes I checked and there are tue cases